# SQLite 5 tables, Join, Sum, GroupBy

Tags: sqlite, join, group-by, left-join, inner-join

I am desperately working on a issue and cannot resolve. I have a SQLite DB with five tables and corresponding columns:

1. **Tab1** = {Job_ID, Company_ID, Source_ID}
2. **Tab1_Category** = {JOb_ID, CAtegory_ID}
3. **Category** = {ID, First_level, Second_level}
4. **Tab2** = {Job_ID, Log_Date, Clicks, Applications}
5. **Source** = {ID, Name}

I craeated a sample db:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB1 (
  `job_id` INTEGER,
  `company_id` INTEGER,
  `source_id` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO TAB1
  (`job_id`, `company_id`, `source_id`)
VALUES
  ('1', '222', '2'),
  ('2', '222', '1'),
  ('3', '222', '1'),
  ('4', '222', '1'),
  ('5', '255', '3');
  
CREATE TABLE TAB1_CATEGORY (
  `job_id` INTEGER,
  `category_id` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO TAB1_CATEGORY
  (`job_id`, `category_id`)
VALUES
  ('1', '31'),
  ('2', '36'),
  ('3', '33'),
  ('3', '35'),
  ('4', '32'),
  ('4', '31'),
  ('5', '34');
  
CREATE TABLE CATEGORY (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `first_level` VARCHAR(3),
  `second_level` VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO CATEGORY
  (`id`, `first_level`, `second_level`)
VALUES
  ('30', 'sss', 'aaa'),
  ('31', 'sss', 'aaa'),
  ('32', 'sss', 'bbb'),
  ('33', 'ggg', 'ccc'),
  ('34', 'ggg', 'ddd'),
  ('35', 'ggg', 'eee'),
  ('36', 'hhh', 'fff');
  
CREATE TABLE SOURCE (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO SOURCE
  (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'mmm'),
  ('2', 'nnn'),
  ('3', 'ooo');

CREATE TABLE TAB2 (
  `job_id` INTEGER,
  `log_date` VARCHAR(10),
  `clicks` INTEGER,
  `applications` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO TAB2
  (`job_id`, `log_date`, `clicks`, `applications`)
VALUES
  ('1', '01-01-1999', '6', '2'),
  ('1', '02-01-1999', '7', '3'),
  ('1', '03-01-1999', '9', '1'),
  ('2', '02-01-1999', '4', '1'),
  ('2', '05-01-1999', '8', '2'),
  ('3', '03-01-1999', '9', '0'),
  ('4', '05-01-1999', '5', '3'),
  ('4', '06-01-1999', '4', '1'),
  ('5', '01-01-1999', '1', '0'),
  ('5', '03-01-1999', '3', '1');
```

I need the following results with one query>

1. list of all JOB_ID (Tab1) and Company_ID (Tab1) where First_level(from table category) is "ggg" or "sss" and Name (from table Source) is "mmm"
2. sum of clicks and sum of applications (Tab2) per Job_ID
3. sum of distinct Second_level (from table Category)
4. sum of applications for each company_ID (a company_ID can have many Job_ids)

This is what I did so far, but is not working the way i want it>

```
SELECT t1.job_id, t1.company_id,
SUM(t2.clicks), SUM(t2.applications), COUNT(DISTINCT c.second_level)
FROM TAB1 t1
JOIN SOURCE s ON s.id = t1.source_id
JOIN TAB1_CATEGORY tc ON t1.job_id = tc.job_id 
JOIN CATEGORY c ON tc.category_id = c.id
JOIN TAB2 t2 ON t1.job_id = t2.job_id
WHERE c.first_level IN ('ggg', 'sss') AND s.NAME ='mmm'
GROUP BY t1.job_id
```

What I get is sum of all clicks/applications and not per job_id. :

| job_id | company_id | SUM(t2.clicks) | SUM(t2.applications) | COUNT(DISTINCT c.second_level) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 222 | 18 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | 222 | 18 | 8 | 2 |

And this is what i want to get:

| job_id | company_id | SUM(t2.clicks) | SUM(t2.applications) | COUNT(DISTINCT c.second_level) | Total Appl per company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 222 | 9 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 222 | 9 | 4 | 2 | 4 |

Comment: Create a fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=22355f54009c7bebe088497f183e80aa with sample data and clarify what doesn't work.

Comment: @forpas i created a fiddle with sample data, the sum part is not working. It is summing all the clicks and applications instead of sum per job_id. A also have no idea how should i get a sum of applications per company: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n3nww3wtszvRABvZcgcG3Z/0#&togetherjs=CxLkjxbOM5

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @forbas, please see above...i just edited the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must aggregate inside `TAB2` and then join (with `INNER` joins).
Also you need `SUM()` window function for the column `Total Appl per company`:

```
SELECT t1.JOB_ID, t1.COMPANY_ID,
       t2.total_clicks, t2.total_apps,
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.SECOND_LEVEL) count_second_level,
       SUM(t2.total_apps) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.COMPANY_ID) [Total Appl per company]
FROM TAB1 t1
INNER JOIN SOURCE s ON s.ID = t1.SOURCE_ID
INNER JOIN TAB1_CATEGORY tc ON t1.JOB_ID = tc.JOB_ID 
INNER JOIN CATEGORY c ON tc.CATEGORY_ID = c.ID 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT JOB_ID, SUM(CLICKS) total_clicks, SUM(APPLICATIONS) total_apps
  FROM TAB2
  GROUP BY JOB_ID
) t2 ON t1.JOB_ID = t2.JOB_ID
WHERE c.FIRST_LEVEL IN ('ggg', 'sss') AND s.NAME ='mmm'
GROUP BY t1.JOB_ID, t1.COMPANY_ID, t2.total_clicks, t2.total_apps
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=057205baa3bbc3b5b0c600b2c96a79ec).
Results:

```
> job_id | company_id | total_clicks | total_apps | count_second_level | Total Appl per company
> -----: | ---------: | -----------: | ---------: | -----------------: | ---------------------:
>      3 |        222 |            9 |          0 |                  2 |                      4
>      4 |        222 |            9 |          4 |                  2 |                      4
```